# Server configuration error on MAMP, preventing email sending - how to fix?

Tags: php, apache, mamp

I have MAMP (normal/baisc) on my Macbook and programmed a simple PHP/ HTML form. The form has 'success' message, but an email does not send.

On apache.log document, it comes up with an error:
[authz_core:error] [pid 87119] [client ::1:60592] AH01630: client denied by server configuration

I have researched the forums, but cannot work out how to change it so that the server can send/receive emails. I am scared of editing a document that impacts the structure of the document, causing more fatal errors.

The /apache/httpd.conf is not a readable file - comes up with error: 'There is no application set to open the document “httpd.conf”'

So, how do I change the configuration so that there is no error on the apache.log documen? Where would I find it in the folders?